Websocket not connecting
I can't connect to the 'wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com' websocket.
When I try it in the terminal with wscat the connection is established, but I can't specify a RPC function that I want to listen to.
When I try it via python code, I get a ping timeout.
async with websockets.connect(WSS_ENDPOINT) as websocket:
            subscription_message = json.dumps({
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "id": 1,
                "method": "logsSubscribe",
                "params": [
                    {"mentions": [str(PROGRAM)]},
                    {"commitment": "processed"}
                ]
            })
            await websocket.send(subscription_message)
            print(f"Listening: {PROGRAM}")

            # Wait for subscription confirmation
            response = await websocket.recv()

I forgot to close it and when I looked again it worked as expected. I closed it and tried again couple hours later and it's not working again.
Is it because the RPC endpoint is unreliable or am I missing something here?
